# Instantly convert seconds edittext (number input) to maximum seconds of 59 if over or limit to 59s

Tags: android

Is there a way to smartly do the above?

I have been doing this instead:

```
            public int checkMinsSpillOver() {
                int runMins = Integer.valueOf(checkMinsEmpty(run_mins)); //checkMinsEmpty and checkSecsEmpty are my methods to check for empty inputs; not important in this question
                int runSecs = Integer.valueOf(checkSecsEmpty(run_secs));
                int runMinsOver = 0;
                if (runSecs>60) {
                    runMinsOver = runMins + runSecs / 60;
                } else if (runSecs == 60){
                    runMinsOver = runMins + 1;
                }
                return runMinsOver;
            }
            public int checkSecsSpillOver() {
                int runSecs = Integer.valueOf(checkSecsEmpty(run_secs));
                int runSecsOver = 0;
                if (runSecs>60) {
                    runSecsOver = runSecs % 60;
                } else if (runSecs == 60){
                    runSecsOver = 0;
                }
                return runSecsOver;
            }
```

Then, I am calculating totalSecs in another method like this:

```
            int totalSecs = Integer.valueOf(checkMinsSpillOver())*60 + Integer.valueOf(checkSecsSpillOver());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the absolute simplest way of 'parsing' seconds into mins, hours is :

```
                long  HH=(TOTALSEC)/3600;   
                long MM=((TOTALSEC)/60)%60;
                long SS=(TOTALSEC)%60;
```